# How to configure the nginx to forward http requests to a specific localhost port through an IP Address and Resource Name?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Is there any way to configure the nginx to forward http requests to a specific localhost port through an IP address and a resource name?

For example, http://1.2.3.4/8000 request should be forwarded to http://localhost:8000.

Thanks!